# Could the 100k+ views color be toned down a little bit?

Tags: feature-request, design

We now have a question that's really, really popular, [Why do programmers write applications and then make them free?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/3233/8), which is fine (better than fine, great!), but the color used for the "on fire" state overpowers the rest of the color palette, drawing attention to the question over everything else:

---

[image: Holy crap that's popular]

---

Could the red be subdued a little so it's not as striking?

*(This is also a problem on comments with a ton of up-votes, but not as big of an issue as comments don't appear on a page everyone visits. Presumably they share the same styling rules, though)*

Comment: 109000??? Whoa.

Comment: Whoa, that *is* attention-grabbing! If we're not careful, that question might attract an unusual amount of visitors.

Comment: It really needs a companion question with similar views, or else people might get the wrong idea: Why to feed, pay, and entertain programmers more?  Given the significance of the attention it has gotten, I think the color/hue/contrast is not overstated.  At least it isn't blinking...